# Find the sum of the series $\sum \limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^5-5n^3+4n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Feel free to skip obvious steps, or use a calculator when required.

I just want to understand the theme of the solution.

Any help is appreciated

---

EDIT :

We can write$$ \dfrac{1}{n^5-5n^3+4n} =  -\dfrac{1}{6 (n-1)}+\dfrac{1}{4 n}-\dfrac{1}{ 6(n+1)}+\dfrac{1}{ 24(n+2)}+\dfrac{1}{ 24(n-2)}$$

How do I do telescopic sum !

Comment: Theme: Factor denominator, partial fraction, telescoping sum.

Comment: I do know that, I tried but in vain, I am still trying on this line

Comment: How far have you got on that line?

Comment: HINT: $n^5-5n^3+4n=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$

Comment: Here is a start $n^5-5n^3+4n=n(n^4-5n^2+4)=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4)$. You should not need a calculator.

Comment: I got it, thanks manos, I will post the final answer soon

Comment: You're welcome 155188

Comment: Added my solution, answer is (1/24). I don't know why the \cancel{} is not working here.

Comment: Did you get this from purple comet by any chance?

Comment: no, this is from stewart calculus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^5-5n^3+4n} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

$ $

Rewrite this as $$  \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+2)-(n-2)}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

$ $

$$  \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{(n+2)}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}-\dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)} \right]$$

$ $

$$  \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{1}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)} \right]$$

$ $

$$\textbf{This is a telescoping sum}$$

$ $

$ $
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{4} \sum_{i=3}^{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{(i-2)(i-1)i(i+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(i-1)i(i+1)(i+2)} \right]$$

$ $

$$\require{cancel} =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4} \cancel{-\dfrac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5}  } \right]$$

$$ + \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\cancel{\dfrac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5}}\cancel{ -\dfrac{1}{3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6}  } \right]$$

$$ + \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\cancel{\dfrac{1}{3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6}}\cancel{ -\dfrac{1}{4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7}   }\right]$$

.

$ $

.

$ $
........

$$ + \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\cancel{\dfrac{1}{(n-4)\cdot (n-3)\cdot (n-2)(n-1)} }\cancel{-\dfrac{1}{(n-3)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n)} }  \right]$$

$$ + \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\cancel{\dfrac{1}{(n-3)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n)}} -\dfrac{1}{(n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot n\cdot (n+1)}   \right]$$

$ $

$ $

$$ =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4} -\dfrac{1}{(n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot n\cdot (n+1)}   \right]$$

$ $

$$ = \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4} -0  \right] = \dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4^2} = \dfrac{1}{96}$$

Comment: oh yes, i will update

Comment: I have added a library to include the cancel command. Please check the work now.

Comment: Thanks @bobbym: works perfectly here (on mac OS X)

Comment: Good solution by the way.